# Attach vscode to a running container on ssh server

Tags: docker, ssh, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I have successfully connected to the ssh server in VS Code using `Remote-SSH`. I can attach the VS Code terminal to the running container on the server but cannot attach the VS Code editor itself to the running container.

When I try to do `Attach Visual Studio Code`, it shows no running container. How can I point VS Code to the list of containers running on a remote server?

Comment: Would love to know the answer to this question as well.